# Convert range of number in string to list of integer

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, string, range

I have a string `"2-6,8,10-15,20-23"`

I need to have it converted to a fully populated range of numbers in an array as below:

```
{2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23}
```

Do you have any ideas how to convert it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a website for getting help with specific problems, not to let others write the code for your. So please show us your approach and where it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do the trick (the procedure is described in the comments):

```
Dim s As String = "2-6,8,10-15,20-23" 'Your values
Dim values As New List(Of Integer)() 'Create an List of Integer values / numbers
For Each value As String In s.Split(","C) ' Go through each string between a comma
If value.Contains("-"C) Then 'If this string contains a hyphen
    Dim begin As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(value.Split("-"C)(0)) 'split it to get the beginning value (in the first case 2)
    Dim [end] As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(value.Split("-"C)(1)) ' and to get the ending value (in the first case 6)
    For i As Integer = begin To [end] 'Then fill the integer List with values
        values.Add(i) 
    Next
Else
      values.Add(Convert.ToInt32(value)) 'If the text doesn't contain a hyphen, simply add the value to the integer List
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 10):

Mark Heath has a course on LINQ at PluralSight that addresses this very well. Using LINQ, you can quickly do this using the example shown below.

```
string value = "7-10,2,5,12,17-18";
var result = value.Split(',')
                  .Select(x => x.Split('-'))
                  .Select(p => new { First = int.Parse(p.First()), Last = int.Parse(p.Last()) })
                  .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(x.First, x.Last - x.First + 1))
                  .OrderBy(z=>z);
```

The `Split` creates an array out of the string. The first `Select` creates an array of arrays that have 1 or 2 elements apiece. The second `Select` creates an anonymous type indicating the starting and ending value based on the array values. The `SelectMany` uses the `Enumerable.Range` method to create a range of numbers from each anonymous object, then flattens it into an `IEnumerable` collection of integers. Finally, the `OrderBy` puts the numbers in order for reporting and other use.

Answer (score 2):

```
 string numberString = "2-6,8,10-15,20-23";

 List<int> cNumberString = getValidString(numberString);

 List<int> getValidString(string str)
        {
            List<int> lstNumber = new List<int>();

            string[] cNumberArray = str.Split(',');

            for (int k = 0; k < cNumberArray.Length; k++)
            {
                string tmpDigit = cNumberArray[k];
                if (tmpDigit.Contains("-"))
                {
                    int start = int.Parse(tmpDigit.Split('-')[0].ToString());
                    int end = int.Parse(tmpDigit.Split('-')[1]);

                    for (int j = start; j <= end; j++)
                    {
                        if (!lstNumber.Contains(j))
                            lstNumber.Add(j);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lstNumber.Add(int.Parse(tmpDigit));
                }
            }

            return lstNumber;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, in C# you will get all records into cNumberString  array

Comment: In this code, your all valid integer value comes into cNumberString Array

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input string is always going to be formatted properly, you could try something like this:

```
Public Function GetIntArray(input As String) As Integer()
  Dim splits() = input.Split(",")
  Dim result As New List(Of Integer)

  For Each s In splits
    If s.Contains("-") Then
      Dim low As Integer = s.Split("-")(0)
      Dim hi As Integer = s.Split("-")(1)

      For i = low To hi
        result.Add(i)
      Next
    Else
      result.Add(s)
    End If
  Next
  Return result.ToArray
End Function
```

The basic idea is to split the input string along the comma delimiter and then check to see if that string is a single number or has a range.

Answer (score 0):

use the [Array.ConvertAll method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx):

```
Dim stringArray = {"123", "456", "789"}
Dim intArray = Array.ConvertAll(stringArray, Function(str) Int32.Parse(str))
```

Comment: That’s not at all what OP wants. And writing `Function(str) Int32.Parse(str)` is pretty redundant, you can directly write `AddressOf Int32.Parse`.